# Не открываются файлы txt, hml на Ngix

Tags: nginx

Сервер ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, обнаружил, что не открывается ни один файл в браузере по адресу: домен/имя файла. Нет доступа к robots.txt, sitemap.hml Как исправить данную ситуацию?
Конфиг Nginx:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.agestor.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.agestor.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 reuseport;
    server_name agestor.com;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/agestor.com/html;

    #set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;
    #set $MAGE_MODE production;

    include /var/www/agestor.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}



# nginx.conf.sample

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset off;

add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location /update {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
        expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ cron\.php {
    deny all;
}

location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте [создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Дело в том, что рабочий эталонный конфиг, который помогает функционировать сайту. Конфиг вполне читабельный и короткий, вопрос только о возможности открытия некоторых файлов, находящихся не в статике. Поможет любая подсказка в какую сторону копать.

Comment: я уже подсказал отличное и работоспособное направление «копания». с огромной вероятностью по мере создания минимального самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера вы и сами найдёте причину неправильного (с вашей точки зрения) поведения. ах, да, на всякий случай, так как про логи у вас ничего в вопросе не упомянуто: смотрите на логи.

Comment: Для начала стоит посмотреть в error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте добавить отдельные локейшны для необходимых запросов, например:

```
location = /robots.txt {} 
location = /sitemap.xml {}
```